# A&M Forms reply to address

Tags: plugin-amforms

I'm using A&M forms which is working great. However when a form is submitted the reply to address is the address set in the Control Panel. Ideally one could fill this in with a variable so that it uses the email address submitted by the end user.

is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Of course a couple of minutes after posting this I find the answer.

All you need to do is put the email field handle in the reply to email address input like this

{emailAddress}